# Git web workflow with dev, stage and live site

Tags: php, git, workflow

I'm a little bit confused about the workflows i've found.
Is it right to have a bare repo, a stage repo , a live repo and a stage repo ?
Isn't it really large for big projects ? I mean, so the space is four times bigger ...

Or what else can i do ? one bare repo, which copies the files ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use branches.
http://progit.org/book/ch3-1.html

Comment: Beat me to it :) glad some1 besides me was thinking the same thing

Comment: Yep. Use branches. [Here is a smart way to do so](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP was asking. I understood the question to be "Should I clone the repo once for each environment or should I copy only the files (avoiding multiple copies of .git). I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep different "versions" of the codebase for developing new features vs. QA'ing "finished" features vs. the stable build out in production, branching in GIT is a good way to. You can have a branch per version, and that ought to allow you to work on whichever version as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would want a combination of branches and tags to follow your work. Here is what we do:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/